# How to build an EF Core model for CRUD operations in .NET using C# for a SQL Server table with an Identity and a computed primary key column?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a simple server side Blazor CRUD app with Entity Framework Core and PFB my SQL Server table.

So far I've spent significant amount of time to find a solution but I failed. I'm able to edit and delete record but I'm not able to insert any record.

For some reason, the `Insert` statement is always trying to insert `D_ID` from Entity Framework Core. We tried numerous options, like, `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` for `D_ID` or   `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` for `D_ID` etc..... No Luck.

If anyone can give it a quick try and find a solution/workaround - that will be sooooo helpful. Thanks a lot in advance,

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_NAME]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [D_ID] AS ('DID' + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT([varchar]6), [ID]), (6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IS_ENABLED] [bit] NULL,
    [ADDRESS] [varchar](2000) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [Pk_TBL_NAME_D_ID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([D_ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT [UNQ_TBL_NAME_D_ID] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([NAME] ASC)
               WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_NAME] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [defo_TBL_NAME_IS_ENABLED] DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IS_ENABLED]
GO
```

We tried numerous options, like

- `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` for `D_ID`
- `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` for `D_ID`

etc..... no luck so far.

Comment: But why though? Formatting an id string like `DID000000` in the database just feels wrong on every level. IMHO use integers for PK & FK columns, and format the display value in the front end only.

Comment: Since you showed table, assuming you are mapping to existing database with unusual primary/unique key setup. Please include in the question the corresponding entity class (and related fluent configuration if any).